# initialization order of static const initialized with functions

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, static

In short, I need to initialize a const static member with some value obtained from a file and keep it thereby same for every object derived from it.

So let's say I've a program -

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
static const int VAL1;
static const int VAL2;
};

int F(const std::string);

const int A::VAL1 = F("1.txt");
const int A::VAL2 = F("2.txt");

int F(const std::string filename)
{
  std::ifstream file(filename);
  int result = 0;
  file >> result;
  return result;
}

int main () {
  std::cout << A::VAL1 << " " << A::VAL2 << "\n";
}
```

Is it guaranteed that static members will be always initialized before creation of objects, because that's what I want :/

Comment: The order of initialization is guaranteed, but only within the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, constant static variables are only initialized within a single source file. However what I'm asking is would they always be initialized before I use their class's freshly created object in main.cpp?

Comment: `VAL1` and `VAL2` will be initialized before `main` is entered, even if you never create an instance of `A` (and in fact, in your example you don't, so I'm not sure what "freshly created object" you are talking about). Your program is good as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static data member exists even when no instances of the class exist, that guarantee the presence of an initialized static member when an instance with automatic storage is created.

An exception of this is when there's an instance of the class with static storage that is declared before the initialization of the static member in the same translation unit, the static variables are initialized in the same order they appear.

Comment: if I'm using `a.h` where I declare the class with its members, `a.cpp` where I initialize this const static var, and `main.cpp` where I include and use class's freshly created `obj1`, is it guaranteed that obj1 will already have properly initialized static vars?

Comment: @hg_git The order of initialization of global and class static variables is complicated (which is an issue if the initializer of one of them may refer to others) - but in any case, all this initialization happens before `main()` starts executing. By the time you are in `main()`, all that dust has settled.